# Linking Excel files to an MS Access form

Tags: ms-access

I have a specific excel worksheet for many different areas in a compound I am analyzing and need to link each one seperately to a specific button on a form in MS Access 2007.  The way that the spreadsheet is set up doesnt allow me to simply import it so I would like to have a button that I can click on the database that will open up the actual excel file.  Nothing I have found so far has been able to solve this so any help will be most appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

You can open any file or application in VBA with an API call to `ShellExecute`.

Put this in a module:

```
Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, _
ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal lpnShowCmd As Long) As Long


Public Sub OpenFile(ByVal File As String)
    ShellExecute 0, "open", File, "", "", 1
End Sub
```

Now you can use the `OpenFile` method to open your Excel file:

```
OpenFile "C:\YourExcelFile.xls"
```

It will open with the default application (hopefully Excel on your machine) as if you clicked on it in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, you can use FollowHyperlink with an application:

```
 FollowHyperlink "c:\docs\myexcel.xls"
```